# Python Windows 7 - Installation Fail 0x80240017

Tags: python, installation, failed-installation

I tried installing Python 3.5.0 on my laptop, running Windows 7, and it would keep returning with a "Setup failed" with 0x80240017 - Unspecified Error.

I've tried running as admin and with the three different installers on the site.

Here is the log file: http://pastebin.com/9yuXv1qK

Comment: There's an [open issue (#25157)](http://bugs.python.org/issue25157) in the Python bug tracker.

Answer (score 4):

I have faced the same issue -unspecified error during installation
Package: python-3.6.0-amd64.exe
Platform: Windows Embedded standard, 64-bit.

Solution that worked for me:

1. Uninstall the corrupted Python installation.
2. Install [KB2999226](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=49093).
3. Install Python as Administrator.

Comment: Before do this, make sure your system has up to update.

Answer (score 2):

It is throwing that error because it is trying to install that KB (2999.. something) and failing. If you try to install that KB yourself, it might fail too, as it has some minimum OS requirements. In my case, it was Service Pack 1 for Windows 7. After installing Service Pack 1 I was able to install Python 3.5.x fine.

Comment: It worked for me too. I wasn't be able to install Python 3.5 until I updated Win7 to SP1.

Answer (score 2):

I collected the required update packages to install python on win 8.1
This topc is related to the following one as well:

Python install failed windows 8.1- Error 0x80240017: Failed to execute MSU package

the packages (I did not check the subset of packages, but if you install the all, python can be installed. There are some packages that requires another one before install, the required one is listed here as well. 
So if the install says "this upgrade is not suitable for this machine" just go on, install other packages, and when you finished, install the remaining packages that you were not able to install before.

clearcompressionflag.exe

Windows8.1-KB2887595-v2-x64.msu

Windows8.1-KB2898514-x64.msu

Windows8.1-KB2901101-x64.msu

Windows8.1-KB2906956-x64.msu

Windows8.1-KB2908174-x64.msu

Windows8.1-KB2919355-x64.msu

Windows8.1-KB2919442-x64.msu

Windows8.1-KB2932046-x64.msu

Windows8.1-KB2934018-x64.msu

Windows8.1-KB2937592-x64.msu

Windows8.1-KB2938439-x64.msu

Windows8.1-KB2959977-x64.msu

Windows8.1-KB2999226-x64.msu

As it can be seen I used win 8.1 x64. The total size of these packages is about 1 GB. These all are downloadable from microsoft update center.

BR,
George

Answer (score 1):

I am also using win 7 home premium SP1 and encountered this problem, I solved it by:

1. Go the Windows Update in the Control Panel
2. Search for the installed update named KB2999226
3. Uninstall that update

And DONE!!!

Honestly, use this method at your own risk as I am just a newbie in programming and have no idea what that Windows Update was for. But I did it anyways.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to install Python 3.6.0 on Windows 7 64x laptop and kept getting stuck on installing KB2999226. So, I read what others did on this forum(Fabio Consultant). A previous post mentioned Visual Studio. So, I went to Programs and Features (where you Uninstall a Program), right clicked on the most recent install of Visual Studio, selected "Change" and did a "repair". Once that completed, I installed Python as an Administrator (right click on  the .exe file and "run as Administrator") and Python installed without a problem. I didn't see that the install tried to install KB2999226.

Details on KB2999226 (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2999226). It looks like repairing Visual Studio corrects issues with CRT. Someone correct me if Im wrong.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case are facing it with Windows 7 for PCs:

Very simple, reinstall Windows Service Pack and repair the Visual C++ Redistributable and bingo, the error disappears.

In case of difficulties, uninstall all the software involved (Visual C++, etc.) and reinstall as the proper sequence.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have an application installed in my computer which has python installation in it. I was not able to search it from normal PC search. Just try installing "everything" software if you have complex installation of software like me.

Once you get the path for python installation, add this path to environment (System's) variable and you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5842
2. Click Download button and Scroll down to see all files
3. Select **windows6.1-KB976932-X86.exe (32-bit)** or **windows6.1-KB976932-X64.exe (64-bit)**.
4. Click Next
5. Install this and then install Python

Happy Coding :)