# Python fail to install on windows 8.1

Tags: python

I'm currently learning web development with Python and Django. But the hard disk of my system failed and it has been replaced. I then tried to reinstall the Python but it fails to install. This is what I get as response:

> "One or more issues caused the setup to fail. Please fix the issues and then retry setup. 0x80240017 - unspecified error".

What does this error mean?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure Windows is updated. Some have had the same error [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32673097/python-windows-7-installation-fail-0x80240017). If that does not work please update your answer with more information such as: the installer log, the windows event log (related items only if you could), and try rebooting/re-downloading the correct Python version for you. Also, what version of python are you using?